# C++ pthreads, main function stops running early

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, program-entry-point

I'm making my first multithreaded program and having some issues.  I based the code on an example I found online, which worked fine until I made my changes.  The main function below makes several threads which run another function. That function runs instances of another c++ program that I wrote which works fine.  The issue is that after the program creates all the threads, it stops running.  The other threads continue to run and work fine, but the main thread stops, not even printing out a cout statement I gave it.  For example, if I run it the output is:

```
Enter the number of threads:
// I enter '3' 
main() : creating thread, 0
this line prints every time
main() : creating thread, 1
this line prints every time
main() : creating thread, 2
this line prints every time
```

this is followed by all the output from my other program, which is running 3 times.  But the main function never prints out "This line is never printed out".  I'm sure there is some fundamental misunderstanding I have of how threads work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

struct thread_data{
   int  thread_id;
};

void *PrintHello(void *threadarg)
{
   struct thread_data *my_data;

   my_data = (struct thread_data *) threadarg;

   stringstream convert;
   convert << "./a.out " << my_data->thread_id << " " << (my_data->thread_id+1) << " " << my_data->thread_id;
   string sout = convert.str(); 
   system(sout.c_str());

   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main ()
{
   int NUM_THREADS;

   cout << "Enter the number of threads:\n";
   cin >> NUM_THREADS;

   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   struct thread_data td[NUM_THREADS];
   int i;

   for( i=0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++ ){
      cout <<"main() : creating thread, " << i << endl;
      td[i].thread_id = i;
      pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)&td[i]);
      cout << endl << "this line prints every time" << endl;
   }

   cout << endl << "This line is never printed out";

   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: You're not flushing your buffers.

Comment: So I need to use cout << flush in my other threads?

Comment: Thanks! It works and I understand now what was happening.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're not using `pthread_join(threads[i],NULL)`.  `pthread_join()` prevents the main from ending before the threads finish executing